# SQLITE UPDATE query replicating rows

Tags: sqlite

I have an update query that when I run it instead of matching each unique row it is replicating the same row through the entire column.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

I have got

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = (SELECT Column1 FROM [Table2] WHERE Column2 = [Table2].Column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Table2].Column2` referes to the column in `Table2`.

`Column2` refers to the column in some table that has such a column. The innermost such table is `Table2`.

So this ends up being the same as `Table2.Column2 = Table2.Column2`.

To refer to the column in `Table1`, specify that table:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = (SELECT Column1
               FROM Table2
               WHERE Table2.Column2 = Table1.Column2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however when I try that it crashed the database

Comment: Nobody can help you when you keep the error message a secret.

Comment: there is no error message the database stops responding.

Comment: Then you did not wait long enough. Or an index on `Table2.Column2` would have helped.

Comment: I waited around 45 minutes. and I have an index on both tables.

Comment: For the speed problem, ask a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: From a little more playing around it is telling me that table2.column2 does not exist when I very clearly does.

Comment: Af for the speed that is not an issue at the moment once I am able to get this to work as I want I will be able to leave it overnight to update if needed